# connecting remote mysql database using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web-applications

I am developing c# windows application.

In that I want to connect to mysql database which resides in another system.

Please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you know how to connect to and query a database, you'll need the following:

1. The [ADO.NET provider for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html)
2. The hostname or IP address of the server
3. A user ID and password to connect with

Add a reference to the MySQL provider.  From there, it works just like connecting to a SQL Server box, except the class names are a bit different and some minor SQL dialect is also different.

Of course, if you don't already know how to connect to a database, you'll need to start a bit slower.  I'd recommend you Google yourself a [basic data-access tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMB_enUS291US303&ie=UTF-8&q=ADO.NET+tutorial).

Good luck!